# Easy to use particle tracking software

Tags: images, image-processing

I'm a physics student and we have to do an experiment.

We follow a microscopic sphere of diameter about 40um for 20 sec, in water.

 The sphere will travel a distance wich we have to measure in function of the time.
So we need some kind of particle tracking software wich gives us (x,y) coordinates of the sphere (we have a 2D situation) per frame.

I searched a lot on the internet for finding programs. But none of them are user-friendly.
We would like to a have a free program, which is easy to use.

PS. We have images of the sphere in .tiff format.

Here are some pictures:

Much light
[image]
Less light[image]

It are the big black fuzzy-looking spheres.

We take an image about every few milliseconds apart.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly this sort of stuff with [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) - either in C/C++, (not too user friendly), or with [python](http://python.org), [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and the [OpenCV bindings](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html), there is a good example of doing this sort of thing with the mean shift algorithm [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/OpenCV_Python/python_opencv3_mean_shift_tracking_segmentation.php), most of the demos show the selected item position on a screen but you can easily output to text or as a .csv file.

The following python code tracks a single image in a video, starting from a fixed position:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/slow_traffic_small.mp4')

# take first frame of the video
ret,frame = cap.read()

# setup initial location of window
# r,h,c,w - region of image
#           simply hardcoded the values
r,h,c,w = 200,20,300,20  
track_window = (c,r,w,h)

# set up the ROI for tracking
roi = frame[r:r+h, c:c+w]
hsv_roi =  cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_roi, np.array((0., 60.,32.)), np.array((180.,255.,255.)))
roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_roi],[0],mask,[180],[0,180])
cv2.normalize(roi_hist,roi_hist,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

# Setup the termination criteria, either 10 iteration or move by at least 1 pt
term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )

while(1):
    ret ,frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv],[0],roi_hist,[0,180],1)

        # apply meanshift to get the new location
        ret, track_window = cv2.meanShift(dst, track_window, term_crit)
```

***N.B.*** This is where you would output your coordinates

```
        # Draw it on image
        x,y,w,h = track_window  
        img2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255,2)
        cv2.imshow('img2',img2)

        k = cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break
        else:
            cv2.imwrite(chr(k)+".jpg",img2)

    else:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

You could also support a sequence of stationary images easily enough, (there is a lot of support in numpy).

If you save the above in a script you can use it easily and you could output the data to another file, (and/or as a graph using [pyplot](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.0/matplotlib-1.3.0.win32-py2.7.exe)).

All the above tools are a) Free & b) Open Source.

***Health Warning:*** It is very easy to get hooked on the python tool chain.

Comment: I'm glad that you are helping me. I have very little experience with Python.
How can you import the numphy module? I have dowloaded it.

Comment: Is there maybe a .exe file or something wich you can just execute?

Comment: @abcdef there is an installer which will install it for numpy is that what you meant?

Comment: I've managed to install numphy, but openCV isn't working. Sorry I meant an .exe file wich is a particle tracking program.

Comment: It is kinda specialist a requirement - a lot of physicists use python for exactly this sort of thing, (along with a lot of other things). - Define "_not working_" in this case.